# Submitting form with AJAX without button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

I'm trying to send a form with AJAX and without submit button. Everything works just fine with submit button, but if I try to submit the form by clicking something else it won't work.

I searched for an answer for quite a while, but didn't find anything useful so far.

```
function ajaxSubmit(){
  var showHideForm = jQuery('#dashboard-hki-subjects-form').serialize();

 $.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
  data: showHideForm,
  success:function(data){
  $('#formMessage').html(data);
  }
  });

  return false;
  }

  $('.show-hide-subject-button').click(function(){ 
    var subject = $(this).attr('subject');
    $('#hide-subject').attr('value',subject);
  });


 $('#dashboard-hki-subjects-form').submit(ajaxSubmit);
```

I'm using Wordpress, so the AJAX is handeled with admin-ajax.php.

Comment: If you aren't using a submit button, then what are you using? And why do you expect it to trigger a submit event?

Comment: yeah why do u need a submit button it will refresh the whole page instead of an ajax call....

Comment: You would need to trigger submit on the form within whatever handler you do use. Simpler to have a button and then users won;t be blocked in submitting via keyboard

Comment: Thank you for quick response! I try to send the form with an attribute of clicked element. I don't expect it to trigger a submit event, but this is how I got it to work with a submit button. I guess the question should be,  how to send the form with AJAX with or without submit event and without submit button.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't use a form at all and just send the data with AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

What if you just use an enter key handler...

Try this:

```
<input type="text" name="txt"/>

$('#txt').keydown(function (e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        console.log('you pressed enter!'); //prints to the browser console...
        ajaxSubmit(); //the function you described in your question...
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the `ajaxSubmit()` to whatever there is you're clicking, otherwise there simply will be nothing on your page to trigger it. E.g., if you want your form to be submitted whenever you click on the `.show-hide-subject-button` element, you have to call `ajaxSubmit()` explicitly:

```
$('.show-hide-subject-button').click(function(){ 
    var subject = $(this).attr('subject');
    $('#hide-subject').attr('value',subject);
    ajaxSubmit();
});
```